# How to scan multiple pages into a single pdf in Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, pdf, scanning

It can't be so difficult! There are similar questions in this forum but they're years old. Anyone has any smart solution on how to do this in a simple way?

I've tried Windows Fax and Scan and the new Scanner App in Win 10. The first one simply doesn't scan to PDF and the second one, although it does, it only saves one page at a time as PDF.

I'm searching for a solution that doesn't depend on what scanner is being used, I know some scanners come with some piece of software useful for this issue but not always.

Comment: You are asking an off-topic question (software shopping). Questions seeking product, service, or learning material recommendations are off-topic. See [On Topic](http://superuser.com/help/on-topic). Try http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/  but please first read [What is required for a question to contain "enough information"](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/336/what-is-required-for-a-question-to-contain-enough-information).

Comment: No need to apologise. Unfortunately there is no built-in program in Windows to do what you want so you have to install some software. The question then becomes what software do I need - and that is off topic here but on-topic on softwarerecs.

Comment: PDFsam has a community/free version that works well - just curious to how its too complex?

Comment: Thank you!!... I just understood there were different places in here, so I that's why I deleted my previous comment. I'll ask again in softwarerecs.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

### It's never too late to suggest Windows applications for How to scan multiple pages into a single PDF.

1. [NAPS2](https://www.naps2.com/):(Not Another PDF Scanner 2)
2. [PaperScan](https://paperscan.orpalis.com/paperscanfree/) Scanner Software.
3. ScanSpeeder
4. [VueScan](https://www.hamrick.com/)
5. OminiPage Standard
6. Readiris Pro 16
7. [CamScanner](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/store/p/camscanner/9wzdncrfhv2s) on Windows Store.

I was amazed by [NAPS2](https://www.naps2.com/), because it's free and open source, and simple as well. It really fits the ordinary user's needs.

I have used `NAPS2` with `RICOH SP112su` for scanning 52 pages into a single PDF, and it worked like charm.

[image: NAPS2 Main Screen]

It's worth mentioning Microsoft Office Scanner on [Android](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.microsoft.office.officelens&hl=en) and [Windows Store](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/store/p/office-lens/9wzdncrfj3t8)

Comment: NAPS works great. As I recall it's free (or very cheap).

Comment: NAPS2 worked like a charm. It is quite a robust and effective piece of software. It is free and open source. Kudos to the developer! (https://github.com/cyanfish)

Answer (score 0):

I have been searching as well and recommend to use the vendor tools.

I know that both Epson and HP support this feature, probably all other major manufacturers as well.

I have not found another easy way with free or included Windows software.

The downside is the sometimes 100MB+ install, sometimes including unwanted tools, of the manufacturer.

Comment: Brother also supports this in the bundled software. But it's named "Control Center" which is useless when you use Win 10 search to find your programme, and can't remember what it was called. (Which is how I ended up here.)

Comment: NAPS works really well.